# PushSharp "Notification send timed out" issue

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am trying to use PushSharp to send notification to my mobile devices using Google Gcm.
I downloaded the sample application from github depending upon that I have written my sample code. below is my sample code.

```
var googleKey = CustomConfigurationManager.GetValueFromSection("appSettings", "GoogleServerAccessKey");
            AndroidPushBroker.RegisterGcmService(new PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannelSettings(googleKey));

            GcmNotification androidNotifcation = new GcmNotification().WithDryRun()
                .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"Hello World!\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}");
            AndroidPushBroker.QueueNotification(androidNotifcation);
```

The issue is though I have used WithDryRun() and upon hooking up request it shows json data with "dry_run": true, but still I receive Notification failed error with reason : "Notification send timed out".

Anybody can tell me what am I missing ?

Answer (score -1):

try to run it without `WithDryRun()`, and see do you get anything in events like `NotificationSent`, `ChannelException`, `NotificationFailed` or `ServiceException`.